# AMPL: Modeling vehicles to departure "every n hours"

Tags: ampl

I want to model that departures from a node can only take place in a "every n hours" manner. I've started to model this using two variables - starttime[i,j,k] shows when vehicle k departured i with j as destination, x[i,j,k] is a binary variable having value 1 if vehicle k drove from i to j, and 0 otherwise. The model is:

```
 maximize maxdrive: sum{i in V, j in V, k in K} traveltime[i,j]*x[i,j,k];

subject to TimeConstraint {k in K}: 
 sum{i in V, j in V} (traveltime[i,j]+servicetime[i])*x   [i,j,k] <= 1440; 

subject to StartTime{i in V,j in V, k in K}:
  starttime[i,j,k] + traveltime[i,j] - 9000 * (1 - x[i,j,k]) <= starttime[j,i,k];

 subject to yvar{i in V, j in V}:
sum{k in K} x[i,j,k] <= maxVisits[i,j];

 subject to Constraint1{i in V, j in V, k in K, g in V, h in K}:
    starttime[i,j,k] + TimeInterval[i]*x[i,j,k] <= starttime[i,g,h];
```

The constraint in question is "Constraint1" where i is the origin node, j the destination node, and k is the vehicle. The index g is used to show that the later departure can be to any destination node. TimeInterval corresponds to the interval intended, i.e. if TimeInterval at i is 2 hours, the starttime of the next vehicle to departure from i must not be less than 2 hours from previous departure. The origins corresponds to specific products (only available from said origin node) whereas I want the vehicles to not be bounded to a specific origin node - they should be able to jump between nodes to utilize backhauling etc. In other words, I want to conduct this constraint without having restraints on the vehicles themselves but rather the origin nodes.

The objective function to "maximize the traveltime" may seem strange, but the objective function is rather obsolete really. If the constraints are met, the solution is adequate. To maximize traveltime is merely an attempt to "force" the x variables to become 1.

The question is: how can I do this? With this formulation, all x[i,j,k] variables dissappears from the answer (without this constraint, some of the binary variables x becomes 1 and the other 0. The solution meets the maxVisits requirement. With the constraint all x variables becomes 0 and all starttimes becomes 0 as well. MINTO (The solver) doesn't state that the problem is infeasible either.
Also, how to separate the vehicles so the program recognizes that it is a comparison between all departures? I would rather to not include time dimensions, at it would give so much more variables.

EDIT: After trying a new model using a non-linear solver I've seen some strange results. Specifically, I'm using the limit 1440 (minutes) as an upper bound as to for how long a vehicle can operate each day. Using this model below the solution is 0 for every variable, but the starttime for all combinations of i,j,k is 720 (half of 1440). Does anyone have any clue in regards of what causing this solution? How did this constraint remove the link between starttime being higher than 0 requiring that x must be 1.

```
  subject to StartTimeSelf{i in V, j in V, k in K, g in K, h in V}:
    starttime[i,j,k]*x[i,j,k] + TimeInterval[i]*x[i,j,k] + y[i,k] <= starttime[i,h,g]*x[i,j,k];
```